# How can I handle shortcuts when LSUIElement is set to YES?

Tags: cocoa, keyboard-shortcuts, appkit

When `LSUIElement` is set to `NO` most of shortcuts are handled by application's main menu. But when `LSUIElement` is set to `YES`, there is no main menu and then no common shortcuts are forwarded to a first responder.

The naive solution would be overriding `performKeyEquivalent:` for each view/window class. But I only want to handle common shortcuts, not special one. So, I'm looking for a better solution.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found this http://cocoa.flyingmac.com/2010/07/cut-copy-and-paste-in-lsuielement-applications/. But that doesn't seem like it's what you want and I guess could just be a last resort. That guide just illustrates how to manually implement the keyboard shortcuts yourself.

EDIT: Just implemented this into one of my apps and it works perfectly.